# MVC Website looks different after publishing it

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My website looks bad online: [ihavenotv.com](http://ihavenotv.com)

[image: navbar looks bad]

[image: no space between divs]

But on my machine, while running from Visual Studio, works fine.

[image: navbar transparent on my machine]

[image: nice spacing between divs]

Also, on the dev tools (F12) there's this error, which is not locally:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://ihavenotv.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I don't know if it's related but anyways... icons work.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to see if the server has the correct mime type mapping for woff2 fonts?

It should be 'application/font-woff2'.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the font issues. The website still looks different than on my computer and I have no idea why :)

Comment: Looking at the CSS, in the sheet with containing the class 'navbar-default', background color is being set to #f8f8f8 and border color is set to #e7e7e7, removing them gets rid of the white nav bar. Are you bundling the css? If so, i'm wondering if it's altering the order of CSS precedence on the bundled (live) version.

Comment: On my machine, the margin-right, margin-left in .row of -15 is causing the videobox elements to have no border. I'm not sure why that would differ from your dev machine!

Comment: on my local machine, bundling takes the bootstrap.css, but on publish, it takes the bootstrap.min.css ;) Thanks. Fixed the problem.